# determine user profile local path and show it on a window - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a script with the ability to determine a specific user profile folder of remote computer and pop it in a explorer window.

I would like run it call like:

```
openUserProfile.ps1 username hostname
```

I started with that code but, nothing good happened later...

```
params($username, $computer)

Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer Win32_UserProfile
```

ideas? thanks!

---------UPDATE----------

Now with this code I can list All profile paths, but I can not store just the one I looking for, tried to put a $username inside a Where but no luck

```
$username = "user1"
$computer = "pc1"

$info = gwmi win32_userprofile -ComputerName $computer | 
Select-Object LocalPath | 
where {$_.localpath -like "*"}

echo $info
```

OUTPUT:

```
LocalPath                                                                                                                                                                                      
---------                                                                                                                                                                                      
C:\Users\user1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService                                                                                                                                                      
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService                                                                                                                                                        
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile
```

Comment: What would be the purpose of such a script?

Comment: Just use explorer to browse to `\\computer\c$\users\username\`

Comment: I have a computer inventory website (lansweeper.com), you can find user/s and his computer/s, I can run dynamic "actions" like `script.ps1 {username} {assetname}` and has some built "actions" like access to c$, but not to access to a userprofile folder directly... so purpose is save some 'clics', also I will re-use the code to scan/report properties like profile folder size.

Comment: Well, first of all you need the user's SID. Which leads to a question - is it a local or a domain user?

Comment: Hi, yes domain users. I have Xp and W7 computers so localpaths can vary betwen `c:\documents and settings\user` and `c:\users\user`

Comment: There are multiple issues to work through. For example, the shell functions are for the local computer, not a remote computer; you have to account for roaming profiles; etc. What you're asking for is not really trivial.

Comment: Probably I haven't expressed well what I need to do, but I got what I need on the marked answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close on your updated code, you just need to match the username in the path:

```
$info = gwmi win32_userprofile -ComputerName $computer | 
Select-Object LocalPath | 
where {$_.localpath -like "*$username"}
```

Then you will need to convert the output to an UNC path:

```
$UNC = $info.LocalPath.Replace("C:","\\$computer\c$")
Invoke-Item $UNC
```

Comment: Pls let me update in your answer, the final part to open the explorer+path

Comment: Just a note: even though profile folder name _defaults_ to %username% it can really be anything. So this method isn't 100% reliable. To do it properly you need to [translate user name to SID](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/2776-powershell-sid-to-user-and-user-to-sid).

Answer (score 1):

There is much more simpler way to determine the local path:

```
$env:USERPROFILE
```

To see all environment variables run:

```
Get-ChildItem Env:
```